# how to create an Extjs app using sencha cmd

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am new to sencha. I need to work on ExtJS and would like to create an app using sencha cmd. I have tried many things but not getting a clear info to create an app with sencha cmd.

Please help me by treating as a beginner to build an application.

Also after the installation of sencha cmd how can we start this to run sencha commands? When I try any command in normal terminal it shows me '`sencha is not recognized`' in windows PC. Also I've given the sencha cmd path in the environment variable PATH.

Comment: its showing me the error "Sencha is not recognized as internal or external command....."

Comment: Did you really go through the Cmd Guides document? There it clearly says- *The environment variable SENCHA_CMD_{version} is set, with the value being the absolute path to the installation directory mentioned above. From the command line, use the echo command to view this variable. If the output is empty, set the environment variable manually.*  http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/intro_to_cmd.html

Comment: If you are really trying to work in ExtJS, I'd highly suggest going through the documentation thoroughly. :) Does save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

After you fix the PATH problem and when sencha works, run

```
  sencha generate app YourNameSpace /where/you/want/it
```

Run this command in ext directory - where you unzipped Ext.

For more details see http://extjs.eu/videos

Answer (score 0):

Along with Path variable try to create another variable

SENCHA_CMD_5_0_0 and set the location of your sencha cmd

after doing this sencha cmd path will present in both path and sencha_cmd_5_0_0 variables

Answer (score 0):

Sencha cmd is a Java Application, be sure you have Java SDK or JRE installed, also add the path to Sencha Cmd executable to your PATH environment variable, (My PC properties/Advanced/Environment VAriables), read the install documentation carefully.

Download [Sencha SDK GPL](https://www.sencha.com/legal/gpl/) or try the commercial version.

You could start generating a basic app or using a predefined template:

```
$ sencha -sd path/to/ext-6.x generate app APP_NAME path/to/project
```

A good starting point for more advanced applications is using the package templates, i.e the Admin Dashboard:

```
$ sencha -sd /path/to/ext-6x generate app -s /path/to/ext6.x/templates/admin-dashboard/ APP_NAME /path/to/project
```

You should run `$ sencha package upgrade` if required.